# ExtJS - How do I pass new config item to component without inheriting a class?

Tags: javascript, extjs, components, viewmodel

In ExtJS 6.02, I would like to add a new item `currentPage` to the config of a component:

```js
      {
           xtype    : 'button'
         , text     : 'Next'
         , iconCls  : 'arrow-right'
         , config: {
            currentPage : 1
         }
         , bind: {
              currentPage : '{currentPage}'
            , hidden      : '{hideNextButton}'
            , disabled    : '{disableNextButton}'
         }
         , publishes : 'currentPage'
         , handler: function(btn) {
            this.setCurrentPage(this.getCurrentPage()++);
         },
      }
```

This is not working, `this.getCurrentPage()` and `this.setCurrentPage()` aren't available.

Comment: From what I understand about the config system, you can't add dynamic configs like this.  You would have to define a class that has this config defined.  If you really needed to do this without defining a class, just add `setCurrentPage` and `getCurrentPage` as methods on your instance config.

Comment: @incutonez Don't understand you well, should I put the functions inside the `config` or outside, as a function component?

Comment: I encourage you to read the documentation on [config](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.3.1/classic/Ext.Class.html#cfg-config).  It auto-creates setters and getters for you.  I'm telling you to simply bypass that and create the setters and getters yourself.